# Save object model with keywords in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using [drum template](https://github.com/stephenmcd/drum) to build a reddit style website and I want to populate my database with some entries. My problem is that I'm not able to add a [Link](https://github.com/stephenmcd/drum/blob/master/drum/links/models.py) and the corresponding keywords. I was trying this (I add a few more attributes to the model):

```
   keywords_list = ['key1_test','key1_test']

   u = User.objects.get(username = username)

   obj = Link(
       link = 'www.example.com',
       user = u,
       pub_date = datetime.datetime.now(),
       title = 'Title',
       description = 'blabla',
       fb_shares_ts = '',
       fb_reactions_ts = '',
       fb_comments_ts = '',
       fb_engagement_ts = ''
       )
   for key in keywords_list:
       keyword, _ = Keyword.objects.get_or_create(title=key)
       obj.keywords.add(AssignedKeyword(keyword=keyword),bulk=False)
   obj.save()
```

It gives me this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: generic_assignedkeyword.object_pk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save your object first, then add the keywords to it! Another option would be to `save(commit=False)`, add the keywords, then `save()`...